# What does "with a thing for" mean in this context?

Tags: idioms

It comes from an episode of "The Big Bang Theory." Here's a transcript found on the Internet:[Big Bang 15](http://www.tvfanatic.com/quotes/we-need-a-hot-15-year-old-asian-girl-with-a-thing-for-smart-guys/).

I was befuddled by "with a thing for"; it looks like "have something" to me.

Comment: Your heading has 'a thing of', while your question is about 'a thing for'. Which did you mean?

Comment: This is about an `idiom`. `single-word-requests` are when you know the concept and are looking for a word to express it.

Comment: You should include the relevant part of the transcript in your question (with the link).  Questions should stand alone to prevent link rot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Thing* is used synonymously with *affinity*.  It only really is heard in the context *have a thing for:*

> *I have a thing for blonde women*
>
> *She has a thing for crime dramas*
>
> *We need someone with a thing for smart guys*

All of these are meant to convey a seemingly inexplicable interest.